# Does JavaScript's document.open support the MIME type parameter?

Tags: javascript, dom, document

Some documentation suggests that `document.open()` supports taking a MIME type as its first parameter. For example: [HTML DOM Open Method (Dottoro)](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvkwlod.php).

I also have an ancient JavaScript textbook which claims you can pass MIME types to `document.open().` But most docs I look at say otherwise:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open

Was this a parameter supported in early JavaScript which has since been removed?

I don't see it in the DOM specifications:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-1006298752
- https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170

This is just for my interest; I don't have a specific use case for the parameter.

Comment: I was trying this today (replacing the active document with an `application/json` or `text/plain`), and it didn't seem to work in Chrome, but I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong. Could someone poke around the browsers (probably the source code) and see whether this capability is still available in some way? Or what the restrictions are on the applicable MIME types -- perhaps it's only meant for distinguishing HTML and XHTML, and other types are ignored. Looking for any info like this, in modern-day browsers, for the bounty.

Comment: If support is inconsistent, is there a way to feature-detect it?

Answer (score 6):

### Chrome

Chrome does not use the `type` parameter.

A `V8Document.openMethod()` method checks the airity of arguments to `document.open(...)` then invokes either `v8Document.open1Method()` or `v8Document.open2Method()`. `v8Document.open2Method()` doesn't even read the first (`type`) argument that it's provided. `v8Document.open1Method()` does read it, and set it to a default value of `"text/html"` if it's undefined. It then passes the `type` value to a `Document.open()` method, but from there it's ignored.

### Firefox

Firefox uses the `type` parameter, but the only accepted non-default value is `"text/plain"`.

A `nsHTMLDocument::Open()` method sets `type` to `"text/html"` if the argument is missing, then invokes another overload. The overload converts all `type` values other than `"text/html"` to `"text/plain"`, and then applies that content-type to the document.

### Detection

The `.contentType` property can tell us the type of a `document` we have. We can't use this to feature-detect in advance, but we can use it to check what type the document was actually opened as, and modify our output accordingly. For example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.open('text/plain');

  if (document.contentType == 'text/plain') {
    document.write("I'm text/plain! :-D");
  } else if (document.contentType == 'text/html') {
    document.write("I'm <code>text/html</code>. :-(");
  } else {
    document.write("I'm confused! Also: " + document.contentType);
  }

  document.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify mime type in a encoded URL that you place as a link.

```
buffer = ...
var blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: 'text/plain'})
var dataUri = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
window.open(dataUri)
```

Comment: Hi @brett-silverman, perhaps it would be helpful to elaborate a bit more here? Maybe by providing a bit further explanation or example?

Comment: I had the same problem. Override the document.write function, to append to a string, then use encodeUri(). Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score 0):

Some context: document.write and document.open have some issues, and for that reason their use is discouraged. See

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
https://www.sitepoint.com/insert-in-place-without-documentwrite/

It is an old DOM API, and back in the day browser maker were not coordinated like today on implementing the w3 spec. (which was the reference at this time, nowadays it is more whatwg)

So there are maybe some browser that have a MIME parameter indeed for document.open, but relying on it could cause error sometimes. So it is not reliable. Use alternatives when possible. In fact it might be removed completely some day. It does not exist in the last dom whatwg spec https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

The answer is: **It depends on the browser**. From the dottoro link provided it seems that Safari and Chrome never supported it.

*To be technically correct it is not a JavaScript API but a DOM one.*

Comment: Both of those links you provide are in the context of using `document.write()` to insert context into a document mid-parsing, which is quite a different situation than creating a new document content with `document.open()`, which we're discussing here.

Comment: These are links to explain the deprecation context.